# jQuery children from jQuery selected object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

So here is code what I have.

```
var template = $("#instance > .template");
$("#instance-" + country + " > .content > .stats > .map > .template").before(function() { 
    var temp = template.clone();

    //how to select descendant?
    temp.children(".amount-all").html(json.services[service].total);

    return temp;
});
```

Do I need to do like this:

```
temp.children(".amount-all").children("blala").children("blalalala").html("blala");
```

Or is there other, easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get decendants that match the selector at any level (as opposed to looking at just *immediate* children like [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) does), like this:

```
temp.find(".amount-all").html(json.services[service].total);
```